# Get continuous line plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'd like to plot something like the image attached. It come from this paper http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v488/n7410/extref/nature11319-s1.pdf (Figure 11D). I know it was done in R, but I don't know the package/function.

This is a subset of my data:

```
SampleID prevo.bact
37.TO.O -3.00468736
31.TO.V -3.42291741
06.BO.VG -2.56462361
37.PR.O  0.91296148
03.BA.O  0.02868464
30.BO.V -0.24479930
```

I ordered the values in crescent way and I tried to plot them using plot

```
mydata.ordered=order(my.data$prevo.bact) 
plot(my.data$prevo.bact[my.data.ordered])
```

This is quite close to the output I'd like to get, but I don't know how to change the points obtaining the vertical lines (no one of the types available in plot is like that) and how to change the color according to a class vector `clD`

```
clD = unlist(lapply(strsplit(row.names(my.data),'[.]'),function(x){x[[3]]}))
names(clD)=row.names(my.data)
```

Moreover, I don't want empty space between the points (like in the picture attached, I'd like a continuum).
How can I get something similar? Probably the basic plot is not the way...

Thanks
Francesca

[image: example of what I'd like to get]

[image]

Comment: search for the parameter "type" in the documentation on plot()

Comment: I tried all the types proposed, but no one is something similr to the picture attached!

Comment: Could you post a larger image. It is impossible to see what you want in the current picture (or at least I can't...)

Comment: I attached a bigger one... basically instead of points, there are vertical lines...

Comment: This last image is larger than the previous one, but I don't think it changes things much... I still can't see anything...

Comment: Unfortunately I cut it from a paper, but the resolution is low. Is there a way to upload a pdf?

Comment: Is the paper freely available (arXiv or similar)? Then just post the link and the figure number.

Comment: I edited the question. This is the link http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v488/n7410/extref/nature11319-s1.pdf (Figure 11D)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I give it a try. I think the reason that the plot looks continuous is simply that there are enough points to create the illusion of continuity. In order to have enough points, I had to create some sample data myself, because the six points you give are not enough.

```
library(ggplot2)
my.data <- data.frame(SampleID=rep(c("37.TO.O","31.TO.V","06.BO.VG","37.PR.O","03.BA.O","30.BO.V"),times=30),
                  prevo.bact=rnorm(180,0,3),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
my.data$clD <- sapply(strsplit(my.data$SampleID,'[.]'),function(x){x[[3]]})
my.data.ordered <- my.data[order(my.data$prevo.bact),]
my.data.ordered$num <- 1:nrow(my.data)
ggplot(my.data.ordered,aes(num,prevo.bact)) + geom_point(size=5,shape="|",aes(col=clD)) + theme_classic()
```

I have used ggplot because I wouldn't know how to colour the data points using base graphics. The option `shape="|"` uses vertical lines instead of points.

This is the figure I get:
[image]

Comment: I got this error using your code Errore: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric

Comment: Did you run *exactly* the code that I provided or did you try to apply the plot to your data set?

Comment: I run :mydata.ordered <- mydata[order(mydata$prevo.bact),] and then ggplot(mydata.ordered,aes(num,prevo.bact)) + geom_point(size=5,shape="|",aes(col=clD)) + theme_classic()

Comment: You also have to run the lines that define `my.data$clD` and `my.data.ordered$num`. `clD` is the variable used for colouring and `num` is used for the horizontal axis. They both should be columns in the data frame that you pass to `ggplot()`.

Comment: How can I define my own colors?

Comment: You can define your own colours by adding, e.g., the following to the line starting with `ggplot`: `+ scale_colour_manual(values=c("green","blue","red"))`. You can use other colour names or give hex codes as well. A good way to colour your plots is also to use `scale_colour_brewer` (google it...). The following page helps to pick a suitable colour scheme: http://colorbrewer2.org/. If you run into trouble, you can still start a new question regarding the colours...